# Show that the dihedral group $D_n$ is isomorphic to a matrix group where all entries in the matrix are in $\Bbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The matrix group is

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
  \pm1 & k \\
  0 & 1  
 \end{matrix}\right], k\in\mathbb Z_n.$$

I know the properties of $D_n$ are that  $r^n= e, s^2=e$ and $srs=r^{-1}$
for $r,s \in D_n$. But how do we use these properties to show they are isomorphic

Comment: Just do the matrix multiplications by hand; break your matrices into two distinct sets, $M_+$ (where the top-left entry is positive) and $M_-$ (where it's negative.)  What does the product of two elements in $M_+$ look like?  What about an element in $M_+$ and an element in $M_-$, or vice versa?

Comment: Can you elaborate just a bit

Comment: Pick two elements in $M_+$; let's say ((1 a) (0 1)) and ((1 b) (0 1)).  What's their product?  What's the product of ((1 a) (0 1)) and ((-1 b) (0 1))?  etc.

Comment: You should be able to enumerate all the elements of $D_n$ and all the elements of your matrix group, and show that for each element of one you can find an element of the other.

Comment: Okay and I did and you result in the matrix either [(1 a+b)(0 1)] or [(-1 a+b)(0 1)]. How can we show a bisection towards them ?  Can we take 1 to be the identity of Zn so [(1 1)(0 1)] to be the identity ?

Comment: How much do you know about $D_n$ besides its presentation?  Do you know how many elements it has, and can you enumerate them (and do you know how to multiply them etc.)?  Once you can do that, the mapping may become more clear.

Comment: The order of Dn is 2n but how does this help?